# How to animate the droplets of rain in the picture?

Tags: javascript, animation, jquery-animate, css-animations

[img to animate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWi8X.png)

Hey all, I was wondering if you can recommend me way to animate the droplets of rain?

Also, make it in a way without the eagle. Plus, to make droplets splash upon contact with the ground(which is the line)

I am a bit of beginner to javascript,  but finished 9 months course and reading eloquent javascript. I need some practice, so I came up with this picture (found it on youtube) as a means of practice.

Appreciate all the help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, show what you have done so far and where you struggle at, providing a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example would help you and us a lot

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are relatively new to JavaScript, this would be very hard to do. You can check out the [HTML Canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) and use JavaScript to animate using using classes and arrays for the raindrops, but without enough knowledge in JavaScript you would probably be better off using animation software

Comment: Thank you I checked out the canvas element. seems like a lot of read, but something useful.  I found some sites with ready-made animations,  but they don't seem to fit the one I intend to do. I guess I will read this through and watch a few videos on youtube before setting out to accomplish it. 

I am not that new, its just that all I have is theory, I need practice, and I got stuck in code wars after just a few tasks 